# What is the proper way to handle assembly version?

Tags: visual-studio, project-management, versioning

I am looking forward to implementing a daily build for an upcoming project.

But before doing that, I need to know how to properly version an assembly.

I have the following concerns:

- **Should each assembly have an independent version number or should they all share the same version?**
- **Should I use a * version for build and revision?**
- **Is revision relevant to daily build?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We stamp all the assemblies within our products with the same version number using the following steps:

- Link all assemblies to an
  AssemblyInfoCommon.cs containing the
  version number info: see [here](http://blog.darrenstokes.com/2007/12/17/ease-versioning-multiple-assemblies-by-splitting-up-assemblyinfo/)
  for an example.
- Generate the AssemblyInfoCommon.cs file as part of the build 
  using (in our case) the NAnt asminfo task, Cruise Control .NET and the SVN revision labeller

In our case, we don't use the * version.  All deployed versions are built on the build server.  We don't worry about version number on our desktops.

Comment: +1 for build numbers by the build server. Builds should be repeatable, which means they should be scripted, and doing them on your desktop makes it too easy to be lazy and "just know" how to do it rather than go through the trouble of creating a build script.

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on what you are trying to accomplish with the assembly version numbers.  If you are doing a ClickOnce deployment and want to do independent downloads of updated assemblies, you will need to have each assembly independently versioned -- otherwise, I think it's often nice to have assembly versions match the software release number.  In more complex scenarios you may need another strategy.

A scheme I used at a prior company was major.minor.revision.build -- so in version 1.0 of the product, the assembly version and assembly file version on each assembly was 1.0.0.1129 (for example).  This made it easy to match up what assemblies were part of which software release, down to the build number.  We accomplished this using a pre-compilation search and replace in each AssemblyInfo.cs file to replace a token with the version numbers provided by our automated build process.

Answer (score 0):

So Each assembly should have the same version which is typically a combination of the release version ie 3.4 + the build number which is a sequence that represents the number of times that release has been compiled on the build server.  The revision is relevant because it demonstrates the number of builds that you have created for that release.  You can really do this in one of 2 ways.  The first way would be that if you planned a release ie 3.4 then when you start working on that release then that is your major version number and your minor version number increments with the build.  Another way to do this is to tightly control the build versions in that when you are ready to perform your release to QA / Regression you set your major version to 3.4 and you leave your minor version number to 0.  You keep things tightly controlled this way until you release.  This way you can control your service pack numbering through the minor version number.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally agree that all assemblies should have the same version number; however, I would make one caveat to that. If one of the assemblies is used somewhere else outside of this project or if it is considered it's own project it should have it's own version number. It should also probably be moved out of that solution and into it's own. The only reason I mention this is that I have seen numerous occasions where people have an assembly that's used in a couple of other places, but mainly in one place and they try and keep the version straight. It's a bad idea to do that. I think the Single Responsibility Principle applies at the solution/project level as well.

As far as numbering goes, I agree with Guy Starbuck (major.minor.revision.build). That's the way I've always done it and it has always worked well.

Answer (score 0):

We have a large app (hundreds of assemblies) with frequent releases (about 1 a month). We went for the "give every assembly the same version" but its a constant source of fustration to me that assemblies for 1 version are completely incompatible with those from another, despite the fact that the interfaces of these assmblies rarely (if ever) change.

If this is case for you then you might benefit from versioning assemblies separately - each time you update your assembly only bother to increment the version number in cases where you actually want to break assembly binding (for example if the interface changes, or the changes are otherwise significant enoigh that you want to prevent someone from accidentially using the previous version).